# discord bot python - async def pega apénas uma frase e o ID

Tags: python

eu queria saber como faço para mandar varias frases de uma vez, exemplo

?say Hello World (IDChannel)

oque acontece é que eu só posso mandar uma frase e depois o ID, eu queria adicionar quantas frases eu quiser e depois o ID

```
@client.command(
    pass_context=True)
async def say(ctx, mensagem : str, id : int):
    amount = 1
    channel = client.get_channel(id)
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await channel.send(mensagem)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eu consegui descobrir com uma ajuda, e para ajudar quem estiver nesse post

````
async def say(ctx, id : int, *, mensagem : str, ):
   amount = 1 
   channel = client.get_channel(id) 
   await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount) 
   await channel.send(mensagem)```
````

Comment: Só lembrando que Ids no Discord são do tipo `unsigned long`. Se estiver utilizando a versão 2 do Python, você vai ter que trocar isso. Caso seja Python3+, está certo pois inteiros são infinitos